# CURL not working in the latest version of PHP 7.2!

Tags: php, curl

I tried to install the CURL in my server but failed. My server is running in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & PHP 7.2 version. I used the command to install the CURL in my server.

The command I used:

1. `sudo apt-get install curl`
2. `sudo service apache2 restart`
   I restart my server using this command
3. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl`
4. `sudo service apache2 restart` Again I restarted my server.

But after this nothing works. The CURL Command is not executing.

> curl https://api.example.com/foo/foo/

The output is nothing, Is there any way to install the CURL which is compatible with PHP7.2 version.

Comment: I followed this [article](https://www.tecrobust.com/how-to-install-php-7-2-curl-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-04-2-19-04-edition/), Now I enabled the CURL in the latest version of PHP7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use the following commands:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-dev php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-mbstring php7.2-intl php7.2-zip php7.2-bcmath`

Then need to restart my server.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me!

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt install php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-dev php7.2-cli php7.2-intl
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```